# mac app store error

Tags: objective-c, macos

I've been trying to submit my app to the mac app store and I've been trying to figure out how to solve this issue:

**Files Only Readable By The Root User** - The installer package includes files that are only readable by the root user. This will prevent verification of the application's code signature when your app is run. Ensure that non-root users can read the files in your app.

I haven't been able to fix this problem for a while and does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Fix the owner with [`chown(8)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/chown.8.html) or fix the permissions with [`chmod(1)`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html)?

Comment: Pretty obvious: You need to change the permissions of the .app folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:

I deleted some files that weren't readable by the system, files that showed a white blank icon

Answer (score 5):

In my case, none of the files were owned by root, but one had no read permissions for group and everyone, but only for my user. I found this by using this cmd in Terminal:

```
ls -lR /path/to/app
```

I then searched for "-----" inside the output from the `ls` command, which found the problematic file.

Comment: Thanks! This worked perfectly for me.  I piped the output to a text file and found two random images that had permission 600 "-rw-------"

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but my solution was to run:

```
cd myApp.app
chmod a+rX *
```

This fixes the permissions and makes the Application Loader happy.

Comment: This is a really bad idea.  You shouldn't be arbitrarily be giving `rX` to every file in the app.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who has been banging their head on this one my experience is the error is erroneous or at best very misleading.

After looking over all the permissions then dragging files in and out of the bundle to test Application Loader the error magically disappeared and the same files with the same permissions ceased to give the same error.

This really isn't a solution but it may be important to know that this error may not be what it seems (tested on 10.9.4).